# Order assertions according to order of growth?

Tags: time, processing-efficiency

So, I have a problem I'm supposed to do in which I am supposed to put the following assertions in order according to order of growth

```
 2nlogn
 0.000001n^3
 1983n^2 + n
 n + 456
 3^n + 5n
```

and I don't know how to go about doing this.  I'm supposed to organize them in a fashion like 2nlogn <= n + 456 <= etc....

I'm not looking for the answer- I just need some advice on how exactly to do this.  I know the order of growth table but it doesn't help me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the order of growth table, that's mostly it!

The other big thing to know is that coefficients and lower order terms don't matter. For example,

```
3n^2 ~ n^2 > 1000n ~ n
```

If that's difficult to understand, imagine what happens as `n` becomes extremely large. `n^2` grows quickly as `n` increases, while `1000n` only increases by 1000 each time `n` increases by 1. By the time `n=1000`, then `n^2 = 1000n`, and as `n` increases even more, `n^2` overtakes `1000n`.

So, for any function like `n^2 + 1000n`, split it into different terms that are added together (multiplication is different, e.g. `n*log(n)` is different from `n` or `log(n)`). you can ignore everything but the largest term, in this case `n^2`. Once you do this and strip away coefficients, just use the order of growth table to get your solution!

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions

Comment: Ok, but then what do I do about putting 2nlogn and n + 456 in order? They both have the same largest term.

Comment: Or do I consider 2nlogn as fitting into the NlogN category and therefore larger than n?

Comment: Actually, they don't. `2n*log(n)` is the product of `n` and `log(n)`, which is different from just plain `n`. Check the order of growth table and see if you can intuitively understand why one of them is bigger! I edited the paragraph about ignoring lower terms in my answer to make it clearer.